# How do I make a revset alias for tags whose names follow a pattern?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-revsets

In my repository, I have tags of the form `version-1.2.3`.  I would like to make a revset alias `new()` that is called like this:

```bash
hg log -r 'new(1.2.3, 1.2.4)'
```

...and expands to this:

```bash
hg log -r '::version-1.2.4 - ::version-1.2.3'  # What's new in 1.2.4?
```

When I tried to do this:

```
[revsetalias]
new($1, $2) = ::version-$2 - ::version-$1
```

...Mercurial interpreted it as subtracting the revision `$2` (e.g. `1.2.3`) from the revision `version`, which was not my intent.

I also tried this, using the `##` concatenation operator:

```
new($1, $2) = ::"version-" ## $2 - ::"version-" ## $1
```

But then `hg log -r 'new(1.2.3, 1.2.4)'` gives me this error:

```
hg: parse error at 13: syntax error
```

I also tried using `ancestors()` instead of the `::` syntax, but still got the syntax error.  Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tested the following that works:

```
new($1, $2) = (::"version-" ## $2) - (::"version-" ## $1)
```

For reference `$1::$2` won't give you the same thing, it means the revision between `$1` and `$2`
An equivalent revset that I would prefer is:

```
new($1, $2) = only("version-" ## $2, "version-" ## $1)
```

According to the doc it is strictly equivalent to what you want:

```
"only(set, [set])"
      Changesets that are ancestors of the first set that are not ancestors of
      any other head in the repo. If a second set is specified, the result is
      ancestors of the first set that are not ancestors of the second set
      (i.e. ::<set1> - ::<set2>).
```

Comment: `$1::$2` is not "revision between" in strict form - it's DAG between $1 and $2 - and I can't imagine real use-case, when it differ from only(). Dangling mergeset from far ancestor of $1?

Comment: Consider two versions out of the same base:http://pastebin.com/kBqniLt8

hg log -r "e2b7d1::aedc1a" returns nothing
hg log -r "only(e2b7d1,aedc1a)" returns b and c

Comment: @LazyBadger: $1 is *not* an ancestor of $2.  They are both branches off of the trunk.  $1::$2 **will not work for me**.

Comment: OKay, okay - you won. But I used and tested **real repositories from real worlds**, not use-cases from tutorials from courses "...for the rhinos" with brain-damaged workflow

Comment: @LazyBadger It's just [standard branching](https://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/StandardBranching) with a separate branch for each release.

Comment: @Kevin - OK, but 1) in Wiki "branch per minor" suggested, not "per release" - you'll got **a lot** of dead branches this way quickly, but it's your choice, no questions 2) you misdirected me by using term `tag` - I saw you tree slightly different

Comment: @LazyBadger: I am using what the Mercurial project normally refers to as a "tag" in the way they are recommended (according to standard branching).  I'm sorry this confused you.

Comment: @Kevin - offtopic, but - you mixed Mercurial's branches and tags totally, while they are different things. "Standard branching" tells only about (named) branches

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81348/discussion-between-kevin-and-lazy-badger).

Answer (score -1):

**Side note**: <strike>`$1::$2` will be more readable and give you the same part of DAG</strike>Only `only()` provides correct result **in all cases**, DAG may fail according to discussion in @lc2817 answer)

I was almost successful in getting answer, but have some troubles (and know no ways to debug) at last step: aggregating all in [revsetalias]

**Preface**

Because parameters are tags and tag() predicate allow to use regexps in parameter - I'll use they

Revset `tag("re:version\-")` show all tags, started with "version-"

Revset with hardcoded number as string show single changeset

```
hg log -r "tag('re:version\-1.7$')
changeset:   2912:454a12f024f3
```

(trailing $ is mandatory, otherwise it will be all 1.7* tags)

My best attempt in revsetalias was `tag('re:version\-\$1$')` - with no errors and no output: I can't get fully expanded command in order to see all processings and substitutions and detect my mistakes with parametrized revsetalias

HTH